# Video Poster Image Not Showing In IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, internet-explorer-9

I'm displaying multiple videos on a page on http://louistocchet.com/commercials/ using EasyHtml5Video (http://easyhtml5video.com/) and only the first video's poster image is showing in IE9 (on Win7 64 bit).  I've done a lot of searching and I've added preload="none" to the video tags to no avail.  I've also changed my doctype to the html5 doctype.  I've also tried making the poster image the background on the video tag, which also did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the jScrollPane plugin conflicts with the video tag in some respects in IE9. Not running the embedded jScrollPane script in the head in IE9 solved the problem.